# SQL Server: Using binary_checksum column on a table best practice

Tags: sql, sql-server

Looking at table definitions on an SQL server database have noticed that the (1) binary_checksum column sometimes includes the primary key `my_table_id` and sometimes does not. What is the best practice?
(2) Also what about the `update_by` and `update_timestamp` should they be included or not?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[my_table] (
        [my_table_id] SMALLINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
        [a] SMALLINT NOT NULL, 
        [b] CHAR(25) NOT NULL, 
        [update_timestamp] DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT getdate(), 
        [update_by] CHAR(8) NOT NULL,
        [my_checksum_col] AS (binary_checksum([a], [g], [update_by], [update_timestamp]))
)
```

VS

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[my_table] (
        [my_table_id] SMALLINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
        [a] SMALLINT NOT NULL, 
        [b] CHAR(25) NOT NULL, 
        [update_timestamp] DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT getdate(), 
        [update_by] CHAR(8) NOT NULL,
        [my_checksum_col] AS (binary_checksum([my_table_id],[a], [g], [update_by], [update_timestamp]))
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be a matter of opinion, but it depends on how the checksum is going to be used.  If the primary key is auto-generated (such as an `identity` or `newid()` column), then including it in the checksum is not very interesting.  At least, you can't use the checksum to find duplicates.

If the primary key is a data key provided externally, then it is functioning as both data and as a primary key.  In that case, including it in the checksum makes more sense.

Comment: @otc . . . Pretty much the same reasoning applies.  If you are using the checksum to check for duplicates, then you have to decide if the most recent update metadata is useful for the purpose.  There is a good chance it is not.